# In angular 7 application, how can i modify this mask input to allow a "-" or digit as the first character, and all other characters as digits?

Tags: regex, angular, angular7, masking

In my angular 7 application I have a method that masks user input.  Currently, it will prevent the user from inputting any value other than digits.  I need it to allow the user to input either a "-" or a digit as the first character, and all other characters must be digits.

```
  maskInputAmount(e) {
    const t = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/);
    e.target.value = t[2] ? t[1] + t[2] + (t[3] ? + t[3] : '') : t[1];
  }
```

I'm coming in midway through this project, there are 3 capture groups in this validator.  This isn't necessary, they previously wanted commas every 3 characters but since removed that requirement.

The maximum amount of characters is 7 if the value is positive (9999999) and 8 digits if the value is negative (-9999999).

Comment: Why not just declare the [input type as a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)? That is exactly why it exists.

Comment: We want the look to be consistent with the rest of the form, so the input field should not have a date picker.

Comment: Whats the purpose of an optional hyphen? When you say input field doesn't have a date picker, does that input field ask for dates? And those dates (day, month, ear) are each separated by hyphen you mean? Also, besides the hyphen part, how many digits will follow and do you have 3 capture groups for date, month and year? Can you post, in your question, some valid and invalid examples of user input for which you want the regex

Comment: This is a business ask, we simply implement what they're asking into our code.

The maximum amount of characters allowed in the input field should be 7 if the number is positive (9999999) and 8 if the number is negative (-9999999)

This is the original code, I'm assuming they wanted to have commas every 3 numbers but since removed that requirement.  I'm coming in, midway through the project so, this is my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

if you prefix your regex with optional hyphen in this way

```
/-?(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/
```

wont that solve your ask?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, still will not allow hyphens in the first or any spot.  This works in regex tester, but does not work with the rest of the code in the method i've posted.

Comment: I'm also open to any ideas for a complete rework of this.  It was originally developed to allow commas, now, our business just wants digits with an optional - that can be entered as the first character.

Comment: this is the codepen where I found it working: https://codepen.io/harshvchawla/pen/QWLzbZM can you create a codepen to show the fiddle?